# Laravel Query Builder: select TIMESTAMP as Carbon object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

Is it possible to select a timestamp column as a Carbon date object using the query builder?
 `DateCreated` in the snippet below:

```
$entities = DB::table('translation_review as tr')
    ...
    ->select('tr.AuthorID', 't.LanguageID', 't.DateCreated' /* <--- this one! */)
    ->get();
```

**Update 1**:
I have solved this manually by iterating over the result set and changing the *DateChanged* property manually, but I am not satisfied with this solution. It feels inelegant.

```
foreach ($entities as $entity)
    $entity->DateCreated = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $entity->DateCreated);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use Eloquent, then you should create a Carbon object manually:

```
$carbonDate = Carbon::parse($data['DateCreated'])
```

Comment: Thank you! It crossed my mind, and I did implement a similar solution. See above.