# Illuminate query builder, how to convert dates to Carbon object

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

Is there any chance to use Illuminate Query builder to get dates as Carbon objects instead of strings?

For example:

```
$user=DB::table('users')->select(["id","lastLogin"])->where("id",1)->first();

$user->lastLogin; // <--- Carbon instead of string!
```

Comment: Query builder specifically or Eloquent builder?

Comment: (to be honest I'm bit confused) I'm using query builder instead of Models

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon::parse($user->lastLogin)`, but I think there is no native way to get dates as carbon objects without using eloquent. An example is [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810153/6193316).

I think working with eloquent models will make the work much easier. So you can set the `$dates` property to get the lastLogin as carbon object. More informations [at laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Comment: I agree, the point is in my application I use few models (like my example) and many joined queries. This is why I'm looking to understand if is there any way to map types in query builder response.

Comment: If there is a possibility, I would also find it quite interesting. Could you handle the joined tables as models too?

Comment: Maybe, but then should I define a model for each query response? I found easier and faster using querybuilder in my case.

Comment: Not for every result of the query, more or less for every significant table (for example: users, posts, comments). Does this help you?

Comment: If I have a query with userId and number of posts, I have to create a specific model for this.  After, if I need a query with posts with its comments count, i need another model... am I wrong?

Comment: @Tobia In this example you do only need the models "user", "post" and "comment". Further you can declare any relation of the models like descriped in the laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

After that you can implement the counting of related models: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models