# How to force data type maddping for select using Mysql and Illuminte Query Builder

Tags: php, pdo, orm, query-builder, illuminate-container

I need to create a select query using Illuminate QB and Mysqsl specifying the data type of some column:

```
$data=DB:table("mytable")->select(["id","isValid"])->get();
```

With the current configuration the "isValid" field is mapped as a string of value "1" and I need an int.
Is there any chance to set the data type for PDO fetch?

Comment: Why don't you try to work with models like we already wrote in your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344180/illuminate-query-builder-how-to-convert-dates-to-carbon-object

Comment: Beucase, as I said in the other question, I don't have a real model to handle but table-crossing queries with many joins.